# How to remove the WIX bundle entry from control panel Add/Remove programs

Tags: wix, wix3.8

I am creating an `MSI` installer using a `Wix` for `wpf` applications.

As a part of this, I had created three projects, one is `Wix` set up project, second is a 3rd party project and another is a `Bootstrapper`. There is a file named **`product.wxs`** in Setup project and **`Bundle.wxs`** in `Bootstrapper` project. Basically the bundle holds the Setup project and third party project together.

After installing the bundle, it creates separate entries for the bundle, my Setup project and 3rd party project in the control panel.

Now I decided to get rid of the bundle and have two separate installers, one for my project and another of the 3rd party project.

Now if I install my setup project on top of the previous install, it updates the previous setup project entry in the control panel, but the bundle entry remain intact.

**Is there a way I can remove the previous bundle entry from the control panel through my setup project?**

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: This is all design behavior of the bootstrapper. After all, it _is_ a package manager. To answer your last question, no; A setup project has no knowledge of bootstrapper-versions that may have, might or might be installing it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply!
But i know the upgrade code for the bundle, can i delete the bundle entry in ARP using it?
Or
Is it a good idea to delete the registry entry at HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall{2061dfef-12s4-483f-983a-2r756737013}, which removes the entry in the control panel?